# I want to write 0 & 1 in binary file in form of bits

Tags: matlab, binaryfiles

suppose i have a vector `V=[0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0]` which contains only 0 & 1 binary digits.presently datatype of vector is double.
I want to write a code in MATLAB which write this vector in a binary file, in such a way that each element of this vectors takes only 1 bit to store in a memory. 
For example as the length of vector V is 10, so when i write this vector in binary file it only takes 10 bits or size of binary file is 10 bits, 1 bit for each element.
Is it possible ?

Comment: `V = logical(V)`?

Comment: I want this vector V to take only 10 bits in binary file. You  can use whatever transformation you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fwrite` to create your binary file and store your data:

```
%Dummy data:
x = logical([1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0]) %10x1 logical array
%Create the binary file
fileID = fopen('myfile.bin','w');
%write your data, choose the right data type
fwrite(fileID,x,'logical');
%Close the fileID
fclose(fileID);

%Check the size of your binary file
f=dir('myfile.bin')
the_size=f.bytes 
%the_size = 10 bytes
```

As you can see the binary file has a size of 10 bytes and not 10 bits ! Why ? Because each element of a logical array is 1 byte. There is no 1-bit data type in Matlab. Due to computer architecture accessing a 1-bit data type is much slower than accessing a 1-byte data type and this is why each element of a logical array is 1 byte.

Noticed that you can still write your file bit per bit with `ubit1`:

```
fwrite(fileID,x,'ubit1');
```

And read those file with:

```
fo = fopen('myfile.bin','r')
bit=fread(fo,Inf,'ubit1')
```

But the variable `bit` is now a double since there is no ubit1 variable in matlab. Also if `mod(number_of_bits_written,8)` is not equal to 0, you won't be able to know where the file end, since your file will have `ceil(number_of_bits_written/8)*8` bits, in this case -> 16 bits or 2 bytes with 6 "useless" bits.

Comment: ya I know that i will get 6 "useless" bits that's why i am asking this, is there any other method to use only 10 bits ?

Comment: @YashGupta. **No** There is no method in the world to use _only_ 10 bits on hardware which are wired for multiples of 8 bits. You have a physical bag with 16 pockets, you place one of your 10 apples in each pocket. Success, you've used 10 pockets only ... but the 6 pockets left empty are still part of the bag. Short of tearing the bag off (=changing the computer hardware), there is nothing you can do about it. And also keep in mind that whether your file use 10 or 16 bits, it will likely have to take 1024 bytes (or more depending on cluster size) on disk.